# Invalid token direct access to this link may lead to a potential security breach

Tags: token, prestashop, prestashop-1.7

After installing Prestashop i noticed that every time i try to access the **Products** or the **Stocks** section in the Backoffice i get the following error:

> Invalid token: direct access to this link may lead to a potential
>   security breach.

[image]

Even though i click the "I understand the risk" button, the error keeps showing.

<s>All the other menus seem to work normally.</s> I've installed Prestashop 1.7.3 on Apache 2.4 with PHP 7.1.

How can i solve this problem?

**UPDATE: Other sections of the Backoffice are also showing this error!**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally solved my issue!

All the PHP extensions were activated in the hosting provider:

[image]

So, i deactivated all except whose necessary for Prestashop to work:

[image]

Bam! Now everything is working as expected.

To be honest, i didn't know this could solve my problem. I just didn't find it necessary to have all those extensions activated.
One (or more) of them was causing the invalid token error, but i don't know which. And honestly, i don't have the time or patience do test them all to figure it out ¯_(ツ)_/¯